# How can a color scheme made with CSS variables be consistent across different pages of the same website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a website that changes its color scheme using a dropdown on the homepage. The color scheme selection works fine for just the homepage, but the user's choice does not seem to apply to other pages on the same website. Here is the relevant code:

index.html :

```
<div class="wraphome diagonal-box">
    <canvas></canvas>
</div>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <select name="theme-select" id="theme-select">
        <option value="light">Default</option>
        <option value="fire">Fire Theme</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

about.html (the other page I'm working on, where the color scheme just reverts to the default :root.light theme) :

```
<div class="wraphome diagonal-box">
    <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

styles.css:

```
:root,
:root.light {
    --text-color: black;
    --bg-color: linear-gradient(-206deg, #000 0%, #000 100%);
    --fill-color: white;
}

:root.fire {
    --text-color: #D62828;
    --bg-color: linear-gradient(-206deg, #003049 0%, #D62828 100%);
    --fill-color: #FCBF49;
}

.wraphome {
    overflow: hidden!important;
    position: relative;
    height: 80vh;
    background-image: var(--bg-color);
}
```

script.js :

```
const setTheme = (theme) => {
  document.documentElement.className = theme;
  localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
}

document.getElementById('theme-select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  setTheme(this.value);
});

const getTheme = () => {
  const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
  theme && setTheme(theme);
}
 
getTheme();
```

index.html always shows the fire theme if choose to select it, but about.html just reverts to the light theme. I've made sure to link the stylesheet and script.js correctly in both pages. Is there any way that the color scheme can be applied across pages without having to select the desired theme on every page? I have found some information on using storage options to save the user's preferences, but if possible, I'd like to stick to local storage. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havn't seen your code in context, but make sure that the document is loaded before you call `setTheme()`. So, I would add the event listener for DOMContentLoaded. I also removed the `const` in getTheme and replaced it with `let`.

```js
const setTheme = theme => {
  document.documentElement.className = theme;
  localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
}

const getTheme = () => {
  let theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
  if(theme) setTheme(theme);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  getTheme();
  
  document.getElementById('theme-select').addEventListener('change', e => {
    setTheme(e.target.value);
  });
});
```